When I run my python script it's saying that a module is missing even though it is installed using Linux Debian
So I am trying to run a python script that has pyarmor and when I run it it says
    from pyarmor_runtime_000000 import __pyarmor__
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarmor_runtime_000000'

But when I pip install pyarmor it says that the requirements are already satisfied and when I do pip list I see that it is installed. I am using python3 and Linux Debian.
I tried uninstalling and installing it and got the same error. The script works on windows so there is nothing wrong with it seems more like a linux problem with python.

Is there a particular reason why you are not following the runtime instructions from the pyarmor docs: https://pypi.org/project/pyarmor/  I'm not understanding the _runtime_000000 in your import ... looks very odd to me.

Please ensure your question is a proper [mcve]. You ran a script, please show it. You installed a package, please show how. You got an error message, please add it, properly formatted, to your question. You ran your script, please show how.

@Mark The error was there, just not formatted properly. I fixed it. That said, it's incomplete, which is not great. For the installation, it seems safe to assume they used pip install pyarmor like they said, but it would help to confirm.

The python script was encrypted with pyarmor but it works on windows but when I use it on linux I get this problem there is nothing wrong with the script it's more of a linux problem I believe

When running pyarmor gen foo.py (as per the docs), pyarmor will "generate obfuscated scripts and required runtime files" (emphasis mine), and put them into the dist/ folder:
$ rm -rf dist/
$ pyarmor -q gen foo.py
$ tree dist/dist/
├── pyarmor_runtime_000000
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── pyarmor_runtime.so
└── foo.py

2 directories, 3 files

In order to run your obfuscated python script, you must have all the generated components available. that is: you cannot just omit the pyarmor_runtime_000000 directory as it is required (e.g. when copying the obfuscated code to another place). Also, the pyarmor_runtime.so file is an arch-specific binary (so you cannot run the obfuscated script on a different architecture. e.g. if you ran pyarmor gen foo.py on a Raspberry Pi, you cannot then use it on an amd64 machine).
pip install pyarmor will provide the infrastructure to generate the pyarmor_runtime_000000 runtime (via pyarmor gen ...), but it will not provide the runtime itself.
